# ProgrammingError while insert list in table using mysql python

Tags: python, sql, list

Here is my code:

```py
import mysql.connector
import datetime
import dateutil.parser
import soundfile as sf

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
host="localhost",
user="py",
password="12345678",
database="mydatabase"
               )
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
print(res )
val = res
sql = """INSERT INTO customers (adress) VALUES (%s) """

mycursor.executemany(sql, val)
mydb.commit()
print(mycursor.rowcount, "record inserted.")
```

The values of list is

```
['2021-05-21 04:00:32.071', '2021-05-21 04:00:33.071', '2021-05-21 04:00:34.071', '2021-05-21 04:00:35.061', '2021-05-21 04:00:36.071', '2021-05-21 04:00:37.071', '2021-05-21 04:00:38.071', '2021-05-21 04:00:39.061', '2021-05-21 04:00:40.071', '2021-05-21 04:00:41.071', '2021-05-21 04:00:42.071', '2021-05-21 04:00:43.061', '2021-05-21 04:00:44.071', '2021-05-21 04:00:45.071']
```

and here is the error:

```
ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement
```

[image]

Comment: ```"""INSERT INTO customers VALUES (%s) """```. Try this? Also, I think it should be ```mycursor.execute(sql,val)```

Comment: same error shown

Comment: Try ```pymysql``` module. I use that module only

Comment: still not working sir

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 0):

full list is not set asd column so that we use for loop herwe is code:

```
 import mysql.connector
 import datetime
 import dateutil.parser
 import soundfile as sf

 mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="py",
    password="12345678",
   database="mydatabase"
           )
   mycursor = mydb.cursor()
   for i in range(len(res)):    
   val = res[i]
   sql = "INSERT INTO timestamps ({}) VALUES ('{}') ".format(colname,val)
   mycursor.execute(sql, val)
   mydb.commit()
     print(mycursor.rowcount, "record inserted.")
```

Comment: Building SQL statements with string formatting methods is very dangerous and should never be done as it opens attack vectors via SQL injection. The loop can be avoided by using the `executemany` method on the cursor object. Also please make sure that formatting and indentation are correct in your code snippets. The above, as posted, will not run.